# About a "cut evenly" statement in Curtis' MOG article

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

I'm studying deeply the Curtis' fundamental article "A new combinatorial approach to $M_{24}$".
On page 2, Prof. Curtis describes two sets P and L, where the latter is formed by lines on P. This is clear to me so far, also enlightened by the Fano plane on page 3.
I checked funny properties on each triplet, which confirms they form a special structure we can call "lines", for example: A + F + G = 0, and this for all the 3 points belonging to the same line.

What's it's not fully clear to me is the sentence at page 2, i.e.:

> We notice that any member of L, say, defines a unique 2-dimensional subspace or line of P; namely the set of members of P that it cuts evenly (i.e. 2-2).

Currently it's clear from the lines after that one i.e. if $X\in t \to |X+t|=4$, and $2$ or $6$ otherwise.
Prof. Curtis gently told me in a private email the "cuts evenly" stands for having an even number of entries in the column or in the rows, but I've tried for example with this:
$|A+c|=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 1\\1 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, which it doesn't seem to contain a even number of entries in all row or columns.

Could you help me in understanding better it, please? I mean, it's clear their sum as $| |=4$, but it's not clear that "even cut".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think cuts evenly means that the intersection of the element of $L$ with the elements of $P$ should have size $2$, so two elements are in and two elements are out. Exactly half of the elements of $P$ will have this property. I could be wrong of course. The exact positions of the elements in the octad should have no bearing on what's going on, they are just useful for visualizing.

Comment: Thanks @DavidA.Craven, I see your point, it could be correct. I also found this article http://eprints.usm.my/6567/1/ON_STEINER_SYSTEM_S%285%2C_8%2C_24%29_AND_THE_MIRACLE_OCTAD_GENERATOR_%28MOG%29.pdf which at the end claims something similar, but slightly different. Is that matching your sentence?

Comment: Looks like it yes.

Comment: "Else if X + t = 2, t cuts those X oddly at 3 points". May you explain better this sentence please? Does it mean, only 3 points in P have that property? Probably yes, so if $|X+t|=6$ we have only 1 point with that property, and the remaining 4 points cuts evenly since belonging to t.

Comment: Where is it possible to get access to this article ?

Comment: Cut means here the number of points of $\Omega$ in the intersection of the element of $P$ and the element of $L$.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven, so probably it's not the same "cut" meaning in Curtis article, since he wrote  "...cuts evenly (i.e. 2-2)."

Comment: @JeanMarie, that's a good question. If you click on the link you get a partial version. I've tried to google it widely, without lucky.

Comment: It looks to me like the same use. Half of the points are on the line, half not.

Comment: That's the Q&A I got some months ago by Prof. Curtis on that subject: The second question is about the "cut evenly" sentence, i.e.: "namely the set of members of P that it cuts evenly (i.e. 2-2)".
It's not fully clear to me the "2-2" meaning, please.

"Cutting evenly" simply means it has an even number of points in each of the columns (or rows, if that is what it's referring to). So an octad cutting the columns of the MOG oddly would have to have 3 points in one column and one point in each of the other five.

Comment: I don't see how the columns have anything to do with it. Where the points are in the grid of eight is arbitrary.

Comment: I see what you mean but I don't think they are so arbitrary. For example they are cherry picked in order to have $X+Y+Z=0$, taken 3 points on P and this, together with the L sets, make them belonging to a given line t. Since there are $70$ tetrads  (or $35$  with complements) on heavy bricks, you can pick of course other $7$ points (+ $O$) on it with that property, so in that sense are arbitrary. So, while you cut even interpretation makes sense to me (and matches the other article), I really think Prof. Curtis was referring to something else. But unfortunately he didn't replay to me further.

Comment: I was also trying to find a rule to generate another 7 elements of P and 7 elements of L with the same properties...do you find a rule for that? Finding a triple is not so hard. The most tricky part is to find a good $t\in L$ which makes a triple $X, Y and Z$ which satisfies $|X+t|=4$.

Comment: I will probably publish another question for this, however, given a triple $X, Y and Z$ a possible $t$ is the one having $2$ dots in common with each point in the triplet. By this way, 2 points will cancel out and will remain 2 points from $X, Y, Z$ and 2 points from t in the symmetric difference.